# Shoplist script and empty list count?

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner in python3. I took the script from [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Lists) homepage
and I changed it for my needs. The problem is that I do not know how to change script input words into numbers (etc. 'str' to 'int' and 'int' to 'str').

Changed script:

> shoplist = []
>
> def main():
>
> ```
>  while True:
>    print()
>    print("---------")
>    print("Shopping:")
>    print("---------")
>    print()
>    print("(1)Add item: ")
>    print("(2)Remove item: ")
>    print("(3)Quit shopping: ")
>    print()
>
>    menu_item = int(input("\tChoose you shopping item number (1-3)?: "))
>
>    if menu_item == 1:
>         name_add = input("\tWhat item you add?: ")
>         shoplist.append(name_add)
>    elif menu_item == 2:
>         print("\tThere are", str(shoplist).strip('['']'), "items in the list.")
>         name_del = input("\tWhich item you remove?: ")
>         if name_del in shoplist:
>            item_number = shoplist.index(name_del)
>            del shoplist[item_number]
>    elif menu_item == 3:
>         print("\tThe following items in the shopping list:")
>         print()
>         together = 0
>         if len(shoplist) > 0:
>            while together < len(shoplist):
>               print("\t\t", shoplist[together])
>               together = together + 1
>         print()
>         break 
>    else:
>         print("\tIncorrect selection!")
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>            main()
> ```

Script output:

> Shopping:
>
> (1)Add item:
>   (2)Remove item:
>   (3)Quit shopping:
>
> Choose you shopping item number (1-3)?: 1
>   What item you add?: tomato juice
>
> Shopping:
>
> (1)Add item:
>   (2)Remove item:
>   (3)Quit shopping:
>
> Choose you shopping item number (1-3)?: 1
>   What item you add?: vodka
>
> Shopping:
>
> (1)Add item:
>   (2)Remove item:
>   (3)Quit shopping:
>
> Choose you shopping item number (1-3)?: 2
>   There are 'tomato juice', 'vodka' items in the list.
>   Which item you remove?: vodka
>
> Shopping:
>
> (1)Add item:
>   (2)Remove item:
>   (3)Quit shopping:
>
> Choose you shopping item number (1-3)?: 3
>   The following items in the shopping list:
>
> tomato juice

**How can I change the shopping section "(2)Remove item:" to numerical count?**

The result should be (Example):

> Shopping:
>
> (1)Add item:
>   (2)Remove item:
>   (3)Quit shopping:
>
> Choose you shopping item number (1-3)?: 2
>   There are 2 items in the list.
>   Which item you remove?: 1

NB! In shopping 2 items count: 'tomato juice' = 0 and 'vodka' = 1. 
Everything else in the script remains the same.

Perhaps is a better solution in python list to use .append, .remove, .pop, .index but I still do not know a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your `elif` statement as follows:

```
elif menu_item == 2:
    print("\tThere are", len(shoplist), "items in the list.")
    name_del = input("\tWhich item you remove?: ")
    if name_del in shoplist:
        item_number = shoplist.index(name_del)
        del shoplist[item_number]
```

Comment: sshashank124, now script section '(2)Remove item:' working but I still have one problem with the script section '(3)Quit shopping:'. If I remove item from shopping list the item don't removed from '(3)Quit shopping:'. There are still left intact tomato juice and vodka.

Comment: @Antsupoeg, What problem do you have with (3) Quit Shopping? Please include in question and then comment here and let me know.

Comment: (2)Remove item: - There are 2 items in the list. Which item you remove?:1 (3)Quit shopping: - The following items in the shopping list: tomato juice vodka. But it should only be tomato juice.

Comment: sshashank124, sorry me but I found out that '(2)Remove item:' still does not work. Calculation is wrong. Example_1(1x) - (2)Remove item: - There are 2 items in the list. Which item you remove?: 1. Example_2(2x) - (2)Remove item: - There are 2 items in the list. Which item you remove?: Item remove in number calculation and Quit items display don't work. Number 2 and 3 not in sync, sorry! :(

Comment: Don't bother responding anymore, I'm looking for solutions from other web environments. Perhaps this task is not so easy as it looks! :)